# Redirect traffic of a domain with lmhost or CNAME

Tags: cname-record

Hello this is my first question and hope later I can help too.

My local domain network is mycompany.net  also I host on godaddy the same domain www.mycompany.net, The problem that I have is when my local users when they type on the browser mycompany.net it goes to a local ip address of my storage unit and I don't want that... I would like to redirect when users type mycompany.net to my www.mycompany.net website on the outside.
I was thinking on creating a lmhost or a CNAME but I would like some suggestions..
Thank you so much
Jesse

Comment: What is your storage unit

Answer (score 0):

One of the many many many reasons you don't use the same domain internally.

If you can, create another site with the specific host example.com, and do a 301 redirect to www.

301 is cached so it won't always hit the server either.